# Instantiating a Generic Type in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a case class that looks like this:

```
case class SomeType[T](x: T)
```

I now want to provide an empty initialization method via a companion object like this:

```
object SomeType {
  def empty = SomeType(???)
}
```

How can I instantiate a generic type? I obviously do not want to instantiate it to null or Nill or Any! Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your question as stated is that `SomeType[T]` has a value `x` of type `T`. What value should `x` take for *empty*? The only sensible answer is that *it should be `Nothing`* but the type `Nothing` is **uninhabited**. That is, you cannot do this:

```
def empty[A]: SomeType[A] = SomeType(???)
```

And you cannot make `x` a by-name parameter (i.e. `=> T`) because you have a case class (and it would be dumb, even if you could, because someone could do this):

```
val st: SomeType[Int] = SomeType.empty //would require T to be covariant
val i = st.x //throws Exception
```

Let's take a step back and start without `x`:

```
sealed trait SomeType[T]
object SomeType {
  def empty[A]: SomeType[A]          = new SomeType[A] {}
  def nonEmpty[A](a: A); SomeType[A] = new SomeType[A] {}
}
```

If you are modelling something a bit like `Option` it's worth thinking about what the fundamental *combinator* it should have is. Here's one way of encoding `Option` for example:

```
sealed trait MyOption[T] {

  def fold[B](n: => B, s: T => B): B //fundamental combinator

  //functionality
  import MyOption._
  final def isEmpty                                      = fold(true, _ => false)
  final def flatMap[B](f: A => MyOption[B]): MyOption[B] = fold(empty, f)
  final def map[B](f: A => B): MyOption[B]               = fold(empty, f andThen nonEmpty)
}

object MyOption {
  //These are effectively the constructors
  def empty[A]: MyOption[A] = new MyOption[A] {
    override final def fold[B](n: => B, s: A => B): B = n 
  }
  def nonEmpty[A](a: A): MyOption[A] = new MyOption[A] {
    override final def fold[B](n: => B, s: A => B): B = s(a) 
  }
}
```

You could make it covariant and make `empty` a `val`:

```
sealed trait MyOption[+T] {
  def fold[B](n: => B, s: T => B): B
}
object MyOption {
  val empty: MyOption[Nothing] = new MyOption[Nothing] {
    override final def fold[B](n: => B, s: Nothing => B): B = n 
  }
  def nonEmpty[A](a: A): MyOption[A] = new MyOption[A] {
    override final def fold[B](n: => B, s: A => B): B = s(a) 
  }
}
```

Or as *Yuval* says below, make `empty` a singleton:

```
object MyOption {
  object empty extends MyOption[Nothing] {
    override final def fold[B](n: => B, s: Nothing => B): B = n 
  }
  def nonEmpty[A](a: A): MyOption[A] = new MyOption[A] {
    override final def fold[B](n: => B, s: A => B): B = s(a) 
  }
}
```

I generally prefer not to do this because I would rather use the combinators than an explicit pattern-match, which is less amenable to refactoring

Comment: What do you think about creating a sealed trait hierarchy with a case object representing the empty case?